# Modifying a Dependency Property from Another Class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I currently have the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCopyEnabledProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsCopyEnabled",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MainWindow));

    public bool IsCopyEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCopyEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCopyEnabledProperty, value); }
    }
```

I have this bounded to a button that I have created to determine whether it should be enabled or disabled. I usually call the following to change the value of IsCopyEnabled from the class it's declared in:

```
IsCopyEnabled = !IsCopyEnabled;
```

I'm wondering how to change the value of IsCopyEnabled in another class (same namespace though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any other class property per class instance.

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
window.IsCopyEnabled = !window.IsCopyEnabled;
```

Because you've registered the DP for MainWindow you can also do this

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.IsCopyEnabled = !Application.Current.MainWindow.IsCopyEnabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

SetValue is a public method. You could call it from another class if you have a reference to the target object:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.SetValue(Button.IsEnabledProperty, !(bool)button.GetValue(Button.IsEnabledProperty));
```